# How to iterate over an enum in Angular 5 via index/ordinal?

Tags: angular, typescript, enums

I have the following enum in the Angular 5 app:

```
export enum Month {
  JAN='January',
    FEB='February',
    MAR='March',
    APR='April',
    MAY='May',
    JUN='June',
    JUL='July',
    AUG='August',
    SEP='September',
    OCT='October',
    NOV='November',
    DEC='December'
}
```

What I'm trying to do is iterate over the values and compare them with a date
field, I have somewhere in the code something like:

```
date.getMonth()  which return number 0-11
```

I'm able to iterate over the enum but I cannot get the ordinal!
I've tried two solutions already:

```
 for (let month in Month) {

var months = Object.keys(Month);
for (let month of months)
```

Both solutions return the string for example "JAN".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an instance of enum and iterate it by Object.keys method

TS file

```
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  month = Month;
  constructor(){

  }

   keyinenum() : Array<string> {
        var keys = Object.keys(this.month);
        return keys.slice();
    }
}
```

HTML

```
 <div *ngFor="let item of keyinenum()">
      {{ item }}
    </div>
```

Update:

If you only want to get Month from 0-11 you can use this method

```
 getValueByIndex(inputindex) {
    var keys = Object.keys(this.month);
    let result = "";
    keys.forEach((obj, index) => {
      if (inputindex == index) {
        result = Month[obj];
      }
    });
    return result;
  }
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-iterate-enum?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: I don't need it on a template. can you update the answer to user the enum type Month?

Comment: I updated answer, is it correct with your requirement?